# View application in landscape view?

Tags: android

At the time of button click I need to show my data in landscape view.
How to show the data in landscape view?

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line in the onClick event of the button.

```
yourActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

The constants that should be used are defined in the [ActivityInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#screenOrientation) class.

[More info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to use a separate Activity to display the data and in your manifest add the following attribute to the activities declaration;

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

You can find more information on that setting at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html